# tor is not working

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, exit-relays

[image: is not working]

```
01/09/2015 10:17:55 ص.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
01/09/2015 10:17:57 ص.400 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050 
01/09/2015 10:18:04 ص.900 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
01/09/2015 10:18:05 ص.300 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
01/09/2015 10:18:06 ص.200 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 109.105.109.163:38980 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
01/09/2015 10:18:06 ص.200 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 109.105.109.163:47779 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
01/09/2015 10:18:16 ص.500 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 15%: Establishing an encrypted directory connection 
01/09/2015 10:18:19 ص.600 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus 
01/09/2015 10:18:22 ص.000 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 25%: Loading networkstatus consensus 
01/09/2015 10:21:40 ص.100 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050 
01/09/2015 10:21:40 ص.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
01/09/2015 10:21:40 ص.100 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050 
01/09/2015 10:21:40 ص.100 [WARN] We were supposed to connect to bridge 'xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx' using pluggable transport 'obfs3', but we can't find a pluggable transport proxy supporting 'obfs3'. This can happen if you haven't provided a ClientTransportPlugin line, or if your pluggable transport proxy stopped running. 
01/09/2015 10:21:40 ص.100 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 25%: Loading networkstatus consensus. (Can't connect to bridge; PT_MISSING; count 2; recommendation warn; host xxxxxxxxxxx at xx.xx.xx.x:xxxx) 
01/09/2015 10:21:40 ص.100 [WARN] 3 connections have failed: 
01/09/2015 10:21:40 ص.100 [WARN]  2 connections died in state handshaking (proxy) with SSL state (No SSL object) 
01/09/2015 10:21:40 ص.100 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
01/09/2015 10:21:41 ص.600 [NOTICE] Ignoring directory request, since no bridge nodes are available yet. 
01/09/2015 10:21:41 ص.600 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.
```

Comment: Have you installed `obfs3`?

Comment: Either that, or a `ClientTransportPlugin` entry: "This can happen if you haven't provided a ClientTransportPlugin line, or if your pluggable transport proxy stopped running."